# mapstruct using mapper inside another return null in test

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I m using mapstruct to generate mappers. when I see in the generated code it is autowired the `Mymapper` in `MainMapper` but  when debug it is  showing that myMapper is null. When I change in the generated code

```
@Autowired MyMapper myMapper
```

with :

```
MyMapper myMapper=Mappers.getMaper(MyMapper.class)
```

, it is working but this is not what I want. I want it to be auto-generated like expected from the framwork.
nb : `MainMapper` uses `MyMapper` , and `MyMapper` uses `Mapper2`

mainMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", 
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, 
    uses = MyMapper.class ,
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_NULL)
public interface MainMapper {

    @Mappings({ @Mapping(target = "year", source = "Period.year") })
    Resource toResource(MyObject myObject);

    @Mapping(target = "Period.year", source = "year")
    MyObject toModel(Resource resource);
}
```

MyMapper :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", 
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
    uses = Mapper2.class,
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_NULL)
public interface MyMapper {

    RequestResource toResource(Request request);

    Request toModel(RequestResource requestResource);
}
```

any help is appreciated .

Comment: Check if your generated mappers are seen by Spring? If you can @Autowired to other class. Maybe here is the problem.

Comment: can you share the code that MapStruct generates?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this issue myself. I was able to get around it by using the **default component model**. Here was my situation:

1. I was using `componentModel = "spring"`.
2. I was trying to utilize my Mappers in a separate Spring component.
3. My `@Autowired` fields referencing the Mappers **were** giving *NullPointerException*'s when running tests.

If this sounds like what is happening to you, you have to use `componentModel = "default"`.
I wanted to use the Spring component model; but, after an hour of banging my head against the wall, I decided to try the default component model.

After changing my Mappers to the default component model and replacing the `@Autowired` fields, I no longer received that dreaded *NullPointerException*!!

### Working Code:

```
@Component
public class Mapper implements MapperTranslator<Output, Input> {
    private final MappingVisitor mappingVisitor = Mappers.getMapper(MappingVisitor.class);
    private final MappingDefault mappingDefault = Mappers.getMapper(MappingDefault.class);

    @Override
    public Output translate(Input source) {
        if (source instanceof InputType1) {
            return ((InputType1)source).acceptAndMap(mappingVisitor);
        }
        else if (source instanceof InputType2) {
            return ((InputType2)source).acceptAndMap(mappingVisitor);
        }

        // default
        return mappingDefault.translate(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am stuck in a similar issue, the generated code has my Mapper which is being used by the main mapper but when running tests, my Mapper is null and throws a NPE. What does changing from `Spring` to `default` actually do? @Matthew K.

Comment: @shapandashore Changing it to `default` means you are using Core Java. You use `Mappers.getMapper()` as sort of a factory method to instantiate your mappers. The downside of using `default` is no dependency injection. This can easily be worked around by using package-private fields and assigning Mockito Spy instances to them from the test code.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew K. Yes, since we are using a spring for all dependency injection, I could not convert the mapper to be used as default. I rather ended up using the generated Impl file for my tests. I found that to be cleaner way to test, even If I need to use multiple nested mappers for verifying funcationality.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was using the `spring` component model, and found this SO thread while troubleshooting. What worked for me was that in my test class, I needed to add these fields rather than reference the mapper class directly in my test method.

```java
@Autowired
private final MyCustomMapper pMapper = Mappers.getMapper(MyCustomMapper.class);
```